# Expect script that tests if a passwordless connection is setup

Tags: beginner, shell, tcl

I have written a simple expect script to tell me if a passwordless connection is set up.

````
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

if {[llength $argv] < 2} {
  puts "usage: test-nopass user server"
  exit 1
}

set user     [lindex $argv 0]
set server   [lindex $argv 1]

set pwd_prompt "*assword:"
set prompt "*$ "

set rc 0

log_user 0
spawn ssh $user@$server

expect {
  "$pwd_prompt" { exit 1 }
  eof           { exit 2 }
  timeout       { exit 3 }

  "$prompt"     {
    send "hostname\r"
    expect {
      "*$server*" { exit 0 }
      eof         { exit 4 }
      timeout     { exit 5 }
    }
  }
}

log_user 1

exit $rc
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of notes:

- `expect` is an extension of Tcl, so you can use any Tcl command: http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/contents.htm

  - specifically, you could write

    ```
    lassign $argv user server
    ```

    which is arguably a bit less readable, but is only one command.
- You can speed up the timeouts: the default is 10 seconds, and you probably don't want to wait for 20 seconds to get the final exit status:

  ```
  set timeout 1   ;# in seconds
  ```
- you never reset the `rc` variable, and the default exit status is zero already, so you can remove `set rc 0` and `exit $rc`
- expect is not bash: you don't need to quote all the variables.
- you don't need to reset `log_user` just before exiting the script.
- expect code written in this style can get pretty deeply nested: The last pattern in an `expect` command does not *need* an action block

  ```
  expect {
    $pwd_prompt  { exit 1 }
    eof          { exit 2 }
    timeout      { exit 3 }
    $prompt     
  }
  send "hostname\r"
  expect {
    *$server*    { exit 0 }
    eof          { exit 4 }
    timeout      { exit 5 }
  }
  ```

  If `$prompt` is seen, then that `expect` command ends, and the script continues with `send`